# Is there anyway to call the NSNotificationQueue like a thread?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsnotifications

Is it possible to run the notifications like

```
-(void) testMethod
{
   [[NSNotificationQueue defaultQueue] enqueueNotification:[NSNotification    notificationWithName:@"TEST123" object:self userInfo:parms]postingStyle:NSPostNow  coalesceMask:NSNotificationNoCoalescing forModes:nil];

NSLog(@"test123");
//.....
```

so that the "-(void)testMethod" go on an execute the NSLog,..., without that the methods, which are called by the notifications did finish.
Is there anyway to solve it, without threads?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking.  Add more code with the expected output shown.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to invoke methods asynchronously.
The answer is NO: you can't invoke methods asynchronously in the same thread.
Check the docs:

> A notification center delivers
>   notifications to observers
>   synchronously. In other words, the
>   postNotification: methods do not
>   return until all observers have
>   received and processed the
>   notification. To send notifications
>   asynchronously use
>   NSNotificationQueue.

Comment: I tried it about the NSNotificationQueue, but I just find out, that when it sends the notifikation, the calling method even has to wait until it finished all called notifikation methods.I think I have to do it about an between threads or OperationQueue und Notifikations.

Answer (score 0):

NSNotificationQueue is not used for asynchronous purpose. 
Reference:
NSNotificationQueue objects (or simply notification queues) act as buffers for notification centers (instances of NSNotificationCenter). Whereas a notification center distributes notifications when posted, notifications placed into the queue can be delayed until the end of the current pass through the run loop or until the run loop is idle. Duplicate notifications can also be coalesced so that only one notification is sent although multiple notifications are posted